# VCF files - examples for haploid organisms

Tags: bioinformatics, bacteriology, dna-sequencing

I am trying to self-learn some aspects of bioinformatics (coming from a stats background), and i am trying to find / download some VCF files for haploid organisms as an input to some statistical analyses. I have seen a few sites where one can download example VCF files for human populations, but there are any sites where i can download some example haploid VCF files from e.g. bacteria as well? I have tried to look at http://bacteria.ensembl.org/info/website/ftp/index.html - but i was not successful yet. That said, as a newbie, i might very much be looking in the wrong location.